# Exponential fit to points by group

Tags: python, dataframe, regression

I have a large pandas data frame in this form

```
Group    X      Y
 1       0.5    8
 1       0.7    9
 2       0.1    2
```

This data frame continues many lines with many different groups signified by numbers.  For each group, I desire to take all the (x,y) points, and fit an exponential curve to it.

I have considered looping through each group, filtering the data frame, pulling x and y into lists, and using numpy to fit the points for each group.  However I’m worried that due to the size of the data frame this will be very slow.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So far, it sounds as if you're missing the `groupby` method.

Answer (score 0):

you are going to love this function it's saved me tons of time the pandas df [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function and [groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) there are good examples on the links.

if the data frame is too big to fit in memory maybe look into [Dask](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html)

at the end of the day you are going to have to separate out by group if you want to run a regression on the group if it's too slow you could use groupby.to_frame to create a different data frame for each group then multiprocess each group or use dask to distribute the fitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) as suggested by the others. If you're worried about performance, try [Bodo](https://bodo.ai) with your code. [Bodo Community Edition](https://docs.bodo.ai/latest/source/install.html) allows you to use it for free on up to 4 cores. It can accelerate Pandas code up by sequential as well as parallel optimization automatically.